# How do you clear the debugging watch window in Visual Studio 2017?

Tags: visual-studio-2017, visual-studio-debugging

I was in a debugging session, and I tried to evaluate an expression in "Watch 1" which was too memory intensive it looks like.  It froze my instance of visual studio and caused me to restart.  This was the beginning of an endless cycle because the next time I tried to debug the same code in the debugger it tried to evaluate the same old expression.

So how do I clean the watch window so that I break free of this vicious cycle?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Had the same problem and solved it by deleting the .suo file. This effectively deleted all break-points  and watches.

Answer (score 2):

Ok, so one way is to set a breakpoint earlier in the code before evaluation for the next run, and perhaps this is the answer.  You can even do a Clear All to wipe out the entire window.

Still, I am curious if there is a way you can do it without running a debugging session.

Answer (score -3):

Simply press **delete button** to remove an expression that is no longer needed:

[image]